# mongo Db unsupported filter type when using Any() or Contains() - Are there any workarounds / fixes?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query

i have seen other threads for this kind of question but none of the highlighted answers work for me.

The piece of code that throws the error is this

```
List<Distribution> distributionPublishQueueList = (mongoDb.GetCollection<Distribution>().Find(Builders<Distribution>.Filter.And(
            Builders<Distribution>.Filter.Where(x => x.Status == EntityStatus.Ok),
            Builders<Distribution>.Filter.Where(x => x.IsActive),
            Builders<Distribution>.Filter.Where(x => distinctDistributionIdInPublishQueueList.Contains(x.Id))))).ToList();
```

The original code was this:

```
List<Distribution> distributionPublishQueueList = 
   (await mongoDb.GetCollection<Distribution>()
       .FindAsync(x => x.Status == EntityStatus.Ok 
                    && x.IsActive
                    && distinctDistributionIdInPublishQueueList.Contains(x.Id)))
      .ToList();
```

but i tried to make it more mongo friendly. Both pieces of code above are the same. The list distinctDistributionIdInPublishQueueList is a list of distribution Id's which are strings. So i am trying to find all distributions which Id is inside of that list + the other 2 filters. When i use the contains inside of the filter definition it throws an Unsupported filter exception. But the following code works because i bring the list into local memory and use LINQ against it:

```
List<Distribution> distributionPublishQueueList = (await mongoDb.GetCollection<Distribution>().FindAsync(x => x.Status == EntityStatus.Ok && x.IsActive)).ToList();
distributionPublishQueueList = distributionPublishQueueList.Where(x => distinctDistributionIdInPublishQueueList.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

I need to be able to not do this in local memory due to the amount of Distributions that are present in the database. Is there a workaround to using Contains and Any. I have also tried using MongoCSharpDriver In statement and Builders.Filter.In and other variations.

An example error would be as follows. This is the code that is used.

```
List<Asset> assetList = (await mongoDb.GetCollection<Asset>().FindAsync(
asset => extractAssetsFromContentService.ExtractAssetFromDraftContent(contentAsMarkdown)
.Any(extractedAsset => extractedAsset.AssetId == asset.Id))).ToList();
```

System.ArgumentException : Unsupported filter: Any(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocWorks.Common.Transformation.Model.ExtractedAssetModel]).Where(({document}{AssetId} == {document}{_id}))).

this would be the same error except the Any would be 'Contains' when using contains instead of any. Similar to a distribution i cannot bring the assets into local memory. All entities share the same base class which Stores the Ids as follows:

```
 [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
 public string Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perhaps show a document sample a which you expect to match and the values you are expecting to match against. Also please include any actual logged errors. For completeness, please confirm if you are actually connecting to MongoDB and not CosmosDB with MongoDB emulation. The "list of strings" might be another different issue depending on what is actually stored in `Id`, but  one problem at a time for now.

Comment: i am trying to match 2 24 digit hex strings; BsonType.ObjectId. The list contains these and the Distribution Id is also a hex string. If you need a complete example data of a distribution i can provide but the only relevant parts are the Ids in this query. The is active and status checks are just searching for non deleted distributions. I can confirm that we are using MongoDb not CosmosDb. @NeilLunn

Comment: @NeilLunn do you require any other information. If i missed anything apologies just point it out for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following solutions;

```
var filter = Builders<Distribution>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Distincts, i => distinctIdList.Contains(i.Id));

var results = await (await _collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
Expression<Func<Distribution, bool>> filter = x => districtIdList.Contains(x.Id);

var results = await (await _collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToListAsync();
```

These two solutions work fine in my projects. I have a [library](https://github.com/Milvasoft/Milvasoft/blob/master/Milvasoft.DataAccess.MongoDB/Concrete/BaseRepository.cs) where you can apply these usages. When you send an `expression` to any of the `get` methods here, it will work. For example;

```
var distributionPublishQueueList = await _distributionRepository.GetAllAsync(x => distinctDistributionIdInPublishQueueList.Contains(x.Id));
```

You can see the documentation from [here](https://github.com/Milvasoft/Milvasoft/wiki/DataAccess.MongoDB).